# How to make a few transitions one after another

Tags: function, lua, coronasdk

I'm currently trying to make a few transitions one after another but I can figure out a way to get many to work in the same function one after each other. My current way (Below) works but I hate how it's so messy.

```
function screenLowering()
  local start = transition.to(backdrop,{time = 1000, x = centerX, y = height/2, onComplete = screenBounce})
end

function screenBounce()
  local bounce = transition.to(backdrop,{time = 250, x = centerX, y = backdrop.y - 50, onComplete = screenBounce2})
end

function screenBounce2()
  local bounce = transition.to(backdrop,{time = 300, x = centerX, y = backdrop.y + 50})
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function chain_of_transitions(object, params, ...)
   if params then
      if params.dx then
         params.x, params.dx = object.x + params.dx
      end
      if params.dy then
         params.y, params.dy = object.y + params.dy
      end
      function params.onComplete() 
         chain_of_transitions(object, ...) 
      end
      transition.to(backdrop, params)
   end
end

chain_of_transitions(backdrop,
   {time = 1000, x = centerX, y  = height/2},
   {time = 250,  x = centerX, dy = -50},
   {time = 300,  x = centerX, dy = 50}
)
```